# Is there a way that I can have two long straight wires that are coated?

Tags: wire, wire-wrapping

I would like to have long, straight, wire that is coated.  I cannot think of a way to put a thin (electrically insulating) coating on a wire, while also allowing that the wire will be long a straight.

Long, in this case, is 16" to 36".  "Thin" probably means the wire is 1-2mm thick.

I would prefer to twine two of these wires (thinner?), so they are stronger together.  This will require I get them straight again.  Not sure how to do that without lots of effort.  If I got the twining tight enough, maybe I could re-coat it so that it looked more smooth despite the twining.

In any case, I'm open to how to accomplish this, and any degree of hand-making or pre-bought.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just buy an electrical wire? What does this have to do with crafts?

Comment: As was said above, could you please explain what this has to do with crafts?

Comment: People use wire in crafts all the time, telling us the intended use would make this a better question, but I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: Flagged as unclear possibly but certainly not off-topic

Comment: Stumbled across this old question.  Looks like it could be even several good questions with a little clarity, if you're still interested.  The missing details that jump out: 1. Is the goal to make a wire or twisted wire straight, or are you starting with straight wires and need to keep them that way?  How to straighten or maintain straightness could be a question on its own.  2. Do you really need **electrical** insulation (if so for what kind of voltage), or is the coating purpose more decorative or to prevent corrosion?  3. What type of strength is relevant?  (cont'd)

Comment: Does it need to withstand tension, or are you more concerned with rigidity (twisting multiple small wires doesn't produce rigidity, and can stretch under tension).  4. What kind of coating thickness do you need (just enough for coloring or corrosion protection, thick enough for some specific purpose, or very thick because it is the coating that will fill the primary purpose)?  5. Is the wire for incorporation into a craft, or is making the straight, coated wire the craft?  (cont'd)

Comment: 6. Is 1-2mm the important dimension, or are you predicting that wire of that diameter will have the strength and characteristics you need?  (e.g., wire of a different metal might produce the needed characteristics at a different diameter.)  Understanding how you want to use the finished wire would be a great help in understanding what characteristics are important.

Comment: I really wish I'd asked better — at this point, I cannot recall what was the scenario that I needed to coat my own wire (pulled/drawn metal)

Answer (score 3):

Well home electrical wire is already prewrapped and [14 gauge wire](https://www.tedpella.com/company_html/wire-gauge-vs-dia.htm) is 1.6mm in diameter.

[image]

House wire has 3 single wires (4 if 3-way) running through the main housing, and it will have one bare wire and 2 (or 3) wires individually coated.  Granted your colors are limited to black, white and red but you can get some very straight coated wires this way.  Just get a length of the wire you need and then strip off the outer shell.

[image]